# Truncated pstricks image

Tags: pstricks

I am attempting to draw a two lens system using `pst-optic`. Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{pst-optic}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-15,-3)(15,3)
\rput(5,0)
{\lens[lensType=CVG,lensHeight=5,lensWidth=0.5,lensGlass=true,focus=3.33333333333,OA=-10,AB=1,nameO=O_1,nameF=F_1,nameA=A_1,nameB=B_1,nameFi=F'_1,nameAi={},nameBi={}]}
\rput(12.5,0)
{\lens[lensType=CVG,lensHeight=5,lensWidth=0.5,lensGlass=true,focus=1.666666666666,nameA=A'_1,nameB=B'_1,nameO=O_2,nameAi=A'_2,nameF=F_2,nameFi=F'_2,nameBi=B'_2,OA=-2.5,AB=-0.5]}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that my image is truncated even though there is a wide space to the left (the "object" does not appear on the very left of the image):

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\lens` uses internally a `pspicture*` environment which clips the outside of the
predefinied area. Use option `xLeft` for the first lens to modify the border:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-optic}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(21,3)
\rput(5,0)%
    {\lens[lensType=CVG,lensHeight=5,lensWidth=0.5,lensGlass,
      xLeft=-12,focus=3.33333333333,OA=-10,AB=1,nameO=O_1,nameF=F_1,nameA=A_1,nameB=B_1,nameFi=F'_1,nameAi={},nameBi={}]}
\rput(12.5,0)%
    {\lens[lensType=CVG,lensHeight=5,lensWidth=0.5,lensGlass=true,focus=1.666666666666,nameA=A'_1,nameB=B'_1,nameO=O_2,nameAi=A'_2,nameF=F_2,nameFi=F'_2,nameBi=B'_2,OA=-2.5,AB=-0.5]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

However, using `xunit=0.6` or so may make some sense:

```
\psset{xunit=0.6}
\begin{pspicture}(...)(...)
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the correct area of the picture as `(-3,-3)(21,3)`. Also, consider placing the nodes (`A',B',...`) in a good location to be easily read.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-optic}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(21,3)
\rput(5,0)
{\lens[lensType=CVG,lensHeight=5,lensWidth=0.5,lensGlass=true,focus=3.33333333333,OA=-10,AB=1,nameO=O_1,nameF=F_1,nameA=A_1,nameB=B_1,nameFi=F'_1,nameAi={},nameBi={}]}
\rput(12.5,0)
{\lens[lensType=CVG,lensHeight=5,lensWidth=0.5,lensGlass=true,focus=1.666666666666,nameA=A'_1,nameB=B'_1,nameO=O_2,nameAi=A'_2,nameF=F_2,nameFi=F'_2,nameBi=B'_2,OA=-2.5,AB=-0.5]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I have an arrow on the left of the picture which is truncated. The truncated part is actually to the left of the image. The "object" is not displayed.

Comment: You mean line `OA`? you set its length twice.

Comment: Actually, there should be an object 10 cm to the left of the first lens and this object is truncated from the image...

Comment: 10 cm is too far (the rays look parallel), if you use 7cm, e.g., you can see the object

Comment: Yes, but my diagram must be to scale, so I must keep these numbers.